# How do I Find the Function I Need in a DLL?

Tags: .net, windows, vb.net, dll

For some functions that I need in a program, I have to add a reference to a DLL. I was wondering how programmers find the DLLs that are required for a function.

For example, if I need to get the Text of the active window, I have to reference "user32".

How do you figure out which DLL you need to import? Do you browse the documentation?

I am currently using Visual Basic .NET

Comment: Is it a native method you need or a .NET method?

Answer (score 2):

Most of the time just google what I'm trying to do, eg:

```
 https://www.google.com.au/search?q=get+text+from+window+in+c%23
```

and I read the top 3 answers.

I also read a few blogs, read a few books, and if I'm really stuck I'll browse the documentation. Though I've found the MSDN documentation to not be particularly helpful at times, but sometime it can be good. Or I'll pick up the phone and ring some of my fellow nerds.

If you're having to reference user32 and a COM DLL, I recommend you check out http://www.pinvoke.net/ but if you're writing VB.NET code and not trying to do anything fancy there's probably a much easier way of doing what you're trying to do.

Comment: For the sake of P/Invoke imports that this will almost certainly need, pinvoke.net is probably the best bet. Not only will it tell you which library to pull from, but it will also tell you what .NET types you need to use to marshal the data.

Comment: *"I'll pick up the phone and ring some of my fellow nerds"* When did you write this answer, 15 years ago? The Internet and Stack Overflow have been invented in the meantime.

Comment: @CodyGray sometimes a voice of experience is worth 1000 google searches. Especially if you're not sure what you're looking for, or if it involves a judgement call.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation for Windows API functions on MSDN always has the library where you can find it at the bottom of the documentation page.

Finding what function you need is a different story, and there Google is usually your friend as indicated in LachlanB's answer.